# How to find words in no-space string with PHP?

Tags: php, string

I have strings like this.

`lasvegashotel`, `losangelesrestaurant`, ...

Like strings has word of "Las Vegas", "Hotel", "Los Angeles", "Restaurant", ...

I should find words from like above string (`lasvegashotel`, `losangelesrestaurant`).

The final purpose is

```
{
'lasvegashotel'=>'LasVegasHotel',
'losangelesrestaurant'=>'LosAngelesRestaurant',
....
}
```

I don't know what words will be inputted.

Please help me to solve this interesting problem.

Keyword is that these strings are not long.

Comment: so the words are same in the final output, just a camelCase, what's the point?

Comment: Thanks for caring...
Words are same

Comment: Please show us your attempt(s) to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: Still have no idea.

Comment: You will need a dictionary of compound words to start with. Otherwise you'll never be able to recognize words.

Comment: Right, I think I need like dictionary. Do you know where can I get like service?

Comment: i think you could use google for this. Use something like html scrapper or google api to search the string and google will correct it for you. Copy this text, capitalize and remove spaces. Watch out for rate limits. Automize it.

Answer (score 0):

So you mean that you have strings like "Las Vegas" and you want to convert them in two other strings, like "lasvegas" and "LasVegas".

To do that, first, we need to delete all the spaces from the strings using the function [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).
Then, this would give us a code like this:
`$basestr = "Las Vegas"; // This will be our base string
$value = str_replace(" ", "", $basestr); // This removes all spaces from $basestr ans saves it as $value`
Then, as you said, you need a lower cased version of the string without spaces.
This time, we'll use an another function: [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php).

This function basicly lowercase every character of a string and returns it.    So the final code would look like this:
`$basestr = "Las Vegas"; // This will be our base string
$value = str_replace(" ", "", $basestr); // This removes all spaces from $basestr ans saves it as $value
$key = strtolower($value); // Gets a lowercased version of $value`

But if you want to it multiple times for every string, then create a function like:

`function getKeyAndValue($basestr) {
$value = str_replace(" ", "", $basestr); // This removes all spaces from $basestr ans saves it as $value
$key = strtolower($value); // Gets a lowercased version of $value
return [$key => $value];
}`
And the call this function for all the strings you want to get.

Have a nice day.

EDIT: Due to my misunderstanding of the OP problem, here should be the answer that the OP asked for:

So we'll still use the str_replace function and the strtolower function, but in a different way.

The answer is pretty simple, we replace any lowercase word from the capitalised one.
Here, I'm assuming you have only one word per string (aka no space to do separate words), if this is not the case, please look on how to do in my original answer.
`foreach($wordList as $wordToCapitalize) {
    $basestr = str_replace(strtolower($wordToCapitalize), $wordToCapitalize);
}`

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the problem.  OP has strings with no spaces (like lasvegasrestaurant) that are comprised of a set of known words (like hotel, restaurant and Las Vegas).  Goal is to find the known words in the string and capitalize the first letter of each word.  So, lasvegasrestaurant would return LasVegasRestaurant.

Comment: Oh ok I did not understand that. But now, without a set of words to capitalize, that's not possible.

Comment: From my understanding, OP has a set of known words which can be used in any combination in the string with no spaces.

Comment: I think it's very different form what I think.

Answer (score 0):

There's no solid, works-for-everything tokenization solution for that requirement.  There is a really good discussion re an approach to tackling it by the incredibly smart guys at Stanford NLP:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBk24DI8kg0&index=4&list=PL6397E4B26D00A269

Basically you'd need a dictionary of words you could attempt to match and pop off the front of the string.  For example, in "lasvegashotel" you'd have a dictionary with "las", "vegas", "hotel" or maybe even combine the bigram "lasvegas" if you wanted.  You'd then have to iteratively search the string looking for matches with longer substrings starting from the beginning of your source string.  Once a token is identified, you pop it off the source string and then begin looking for the next match.

The problem with this solution is that "las" would not only get tokenized from "lasvegas" but also from "lastmanstanding."  There are workarounds, but there's no silver bullet solution.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.
It's good. But Still no have perfect answer. Do you have idea of getting all words?

Comment: @Angel what do you mean by "getting all words?"  From the string, or a dictionary to use for tokenizing the non-delimited string?